# Normalization of one-to-many (fixed number) relation

Tags: sql, relational-database, one-to-many, normalization, data-modeling

I need to model a team with maximum 5 members, each member having a different role. A role can be unassigned, and so the team will have fewer than 5 members. The maximum amount of members is not likely to change in the future. A user can only be member of one team.

**Added**: An administrator can assign users to teams. An adminstrator has ownership of the User entity.

I am in doubt whether to do normalization or not, and I wonder which datamodel will leave me with the best performance.

If not doing normalization I would have this datamodel for Team (with foreign keys to the User table, where the members are represented):

```
role1 (User FK)
role2 (User FK)
role3 (User FK)
role4 (User FK)
role5 (User FK)
```

If normalizing, I would have a relation between a user and a team:

```
team_id (Team FK)
user_id (User FK)
role (ENUM)
```

**Edit:** For an Administrator I need to be able to find all teams in which an owned User is member.
Further I need to be able to find teams where one or more given roles isn't occupied by a member.

I can see pros and cons with both doing and not doing normalization. Of the two queries above, the first seems to benefit from normalization while the second one benefits from the flattened datamodel.

Your input is appreciated!

Comment: Quoting your question: "A user can only be member of one team." and then "For a user I need to be able to find all teams in which he is member". So, a user will belong to just one team or to multiple teams? Could you please explain?

Comment: I simplified the model before asking the question - thanks for noticing the glitch and notifying me.
I have edited the question.

Comment: *"I wonder which datamodel will leave me with the best performance."* How many millions of team members and users do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your denormalization solution is an example of a repeating group, where the the parent (team) knows something of it's children (members).  That's a serious antipattern, and even if you remain limited to 5 team members forever it will mess up future query requirements.  You can easily satisfy both queries with a different kind of denormalization which only has aggregate knowledge of the SET of its children.

Add a child table for TeamMember with references to Team, User, and Role.  This will give you all the benefits of normalization.  Then add either a boolean flag to Team for all_roles_are_occupied or a integer for number_of_members.  Yes, you have to maintain the field, but it will give you all the speed you need and much more flexibility to query and to evolve.  This is analogous to an account entity, like a bank account, where it has a column for balance although it's really just a sum of all its transaction amounts.